# HTML & PHP - Image (.png file type) not displaying

Tags: php, html, image, png, src

I'm trying to display an image but it doesn't show anything although I got the correct URL for the image in my server. Here's my current progress/**Output**:

[image]

**PHP Snippet Code**

```
$Report_ID = 51;
$Retrieval_Image_Query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT Image_Name,Original_Image_Directory,RGB_Image_Directory FROM Report_Image WHERE Report_ID = $Report_ID");

//REMOVES THE FOLLOWING WORDS IN THE STRING BECAUSE IT RESULTS IN A WRONG URL

$Result = mysqli_fetch_object($Retrieval_Image_Query);
$Temp_Orig_Image = str_replace("/home/u871055686/domains/", '', $Result->Original_Image_Directory);
$Temp_RGB_Image = str_replace("/home/u871055686/domains/", '', $Result->RGB_Image_Directory);

$Final_String["Original_Image_Directory"] = preg_replace("/\bpublic_html\b/", '', $Temp_Orig_Image);
$Final_String["RGB_Image_Directory"]  = preg_replace("/\bpublic_html\b/", '', $Temp_RGB_Image);
$Final_String["Image_Name"] = $Result->Image_Name;


?> 
<img src = "<?php echo $Final_String["Original_Image_Directory"]; ?>" width = "250" height = "250" alt = "Working"/>
<?php

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($Final_String);
echo "</pre><br>";

echo json_encode($Final_String);
```

It outputs this URL: [fireoutph.com//Report_Images/Orig_Nov_2,_2018_9:33:20_PM.png](http://fireoutph.com//Report_Images/Orig_Nov_2,_2018_9:33:20_PM.png)

But when I tried to open that link in my web browser (google chrome) it shows me the image file with no problem. Notice the double slash in the URL.

**QUESTION**

> What might be the problem if there's no problem in data retrieval of image path and file type? and How can I display the image successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `http://` before the image URL:

```
http://fireoutph.com//Report_Images/Orig_Nov_2,_2018_9:33:20_PM.png
```

Comment: The OP is asking why `fireoutph.com//Report_Images` (notice the `//`) is not an error.

Comment: It actually solved my problem, i just concatenated the http:// at the beginning of the URL and it solved my problem